# Android custom design with circle

Tags: android, xml

I want to design a section in android like this:

[image]

[image]

83 is the text which would be dynamically changing for each profile. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

you can place both the textview and image in a frame layout and update them dynamically.

```
<FrameLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blue_bg"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="83"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

something like this, hope this helps :)
 -Sathya

Comment: I cannot put a complete image like banner to have landscape & portrait to work well. I want to do it without using images maybe?